# Spring Security Java configuration for authenticated users with a role

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am trying to configure Spring Security using Java configuration with Spring Boot.

My WebSecurityConfig class has a configure method like this

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/", "/login", "/css/**", "/js/**", "/img/**", "/bootstrap/**" ).permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/individual", "/application", "/upload").hasRole("USER")
        .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .successHandler(successHandler);

}
```

I get the login page fine for unauthenticated users, and the user authenticates. However, when trying to access the url /individual I get a 403 error and this in the log

```
2015-11-12 13:59:46.373 DEBUG 34468 --- [nio-8090-exec-6] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/individual'; against '/'
2015-11-12 13:59:46.373 DEBUG 34468 --- [nio-8090-exec-6] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/individual'; against '/login'
2015-11-12 13:59:46.373 DEBUG 34468 --- [nio-8090-exec-6] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/individual'; against '/css/**'
2015-11-12 13:59:46.373 DEBUG 34468 --- [nio-8090-exec-6] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/individual'; against '/js/**'
2015-11-12 13:59:46.374 DEBUG 34468 --- [nio-8090-exec-6] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/individual'; against '/img/**'
2015-11-12 13:59:46.374 DEBUG 34468 --- [nio-8090-exec-6] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/individual'; against '/bootstrap/**'
2015-11-12 13:59:46.374 DEBUG 34468 --- [nio-8090-exec-6] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/individual'; against '/individual'
2015-11-12 13:59:46.374 DEBUG 34468 --- [nio-8090-exec-6] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /individual; Attributes: [hasRole('ROLE_USER')]
2015-11-12 13:59:46.374 DEBUG 34468 --- [nio-8090-exec-6] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@4c2eda81: Principal: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@4c0ab982: Username: foo@bar.com; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: USER; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@fffc7f0c: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: 6E0BF830C070912EAC0050D1285D5CF9; Granted Authorities: USER
2015-11-12 13:59:46.374 DEBUG 34468 --- [nio-8090-exec-6] o.s.s.access.vote.AffirmativeBased       : Voter: org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter@6f192fd7, returned: -1
2015-11-12 13:59:46.386 DEBUG 34468 --- [nio-8090-exec-6] o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter     : Access is denied (user is not anonymous); delegating to AccessDeniedHandler
```

if I replace `.hasRole("USER")` with `.authenticated()` it works and the user gets the page desired, but no role is being checked.

I cannot figure out how to specify that the user must be authenticated and have the role USER. I have looked at many examples and tried many combinations but I cannot get it to work as desired. Most of the examples refer to older XML based configuration as well, which I want to avoid.

What do I need to do to specify that certain URL patterns can be accessed with authenticated users with certain roles?

As requested, the success handler method looks like this

```
@Override
public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication auth)
        throws IOException, ServletException {

    // Here we want to check whether the user has already started the process and redirect to the appropriate stage

    log.info("User {} has been authenticated", auth.getName());

    if(auth.getName().equals("foo@bar.com"))
    {
        redirectStrategy.sendRedirect(request, response, "/individual");
        return;
    }


    redirectStrategy.sendRedirect(request, response, "/application");

}
```

Note that this is early stage WIP, per the comments in the code. I know this works as the log message appears and without the role check in the WebSecurity class the desired page is served.

EDIT : noticed a typo in the question referring to roleService.getDefaultRole(). This was a mistake and has been corrected.

Comment: Don't give role as USER, but ROLE_USER.

Comment: See the answer below & comment, that causes a config exception

Comment: Show me the code where you assign roles to user when they are logging in.

Comment: The log output shows that the user object has the granted authority USER, so I know it is getting assigned to the user

Comment: As per my answer, it either needs to be ROLE_USER assigned to foo@bar.com OR you check for `hasAuthority` instead of `hasRole`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think your logged in user foo@bar.com has the wrong authorities set. In the log you can see the authorities are ['USER'], but since you are working with roles it should be ['ROLE_USER']. Where do you define the authorities for foo@bar.com?

Otherwise try switching

```
.antMatchers("/individual", "/application", "/upload").hasRole("USER")
```

to

```
.antMatchers("/individual", "/application", "/upload").hasAuthority("USER")
```

Comment: Thanks ! I did not see your answer until I'd figured it out myself as well. The documentation is not clear on this.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved my own question, thanks in part to the various suggestions here making me research it differently. Also noted that FrontierPsychiatrist provided the answer as well, but I did not spot the response while I was working on it.

The problem is that Spring interchangably refers to ROLES and AUTHORITIES.

Having implemented the `UserDetailsService` interface to allow Spring to load user records from the application database, I was creating an instance of `org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User` and setting the granted **authorities**. It can be seen in the log statements that the User object had that - `Granted Authorities: USER`, but then my security config was checking for a role, and failing. The solution, simply, was to check for an authority instead. I have also cleaned up the config to separate the URL patterns to be ignored from security from the authentication & authorisation. Complete code snippet below

```
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web
        .ignoring()
            .antMatchers( "/css/**", "/js/**", "/img/**", "/bootstrap/**");
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/individual","/application", "/upload").hasAuthority("USER")
            .and()
        .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .successHandler(successHandler)
            .permitAll()
            .and()
        .logout()
            .deleteCookies("remove")
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout")
            .permitAll();   
}
```

I really hope this helps others when using Java based configuration with Spring 4 MVC.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your configuration something like this.

```
http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/individual","/application", "/upload")
                .hasRole("USER").and().authorizeRequests().anyRequest()
                .authenticated().and()
        .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .successHandler(successHandler);
```

and if you don't want all the request to be authenticated you can replace `anyRequest()` method with `antMatchers("/urls-goes-here")`

Comment: That doesn't work. anyRequest().authenticated() means /login cannot be accessed, resulting in a redirect loop. removing that means all pages are accessible

Comment: Add url pattern in antMatchers instead anyRequest and then call authenticated on it. I have mentiond that in my post.

Answer (score -1):

Here's a tutorial that does what you're trying to implement:

http://www.jcombat.com/spring/custom-authentication-success-handler-with-spring-security

I'm guessing you forgot to set the session attributes in your handler:

```
    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    session.setAttribute("uname", authUser.getUsername());  
    session.setAttribute("authorities", authentication.getAuthorities());
```

Comment: Spring adds "ROLE_" transparently for role matching. If you look the examples is fine with just "USER".

Comment: I tried that, but you get an exception Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: role should not start with 'ROLE_' since it is automatically inserted. Got 'ROLE_USER'

Comment: Alright, my bad. Rest looks fine, Can you edit your original post to include your custom success handler?

Comment: Updated my answer with a tutorial link, please check it out and tell us if it worked

Comment: That transfers the responsibility for checking roles to the success handler but only at the point of login. That would not be checked at any other time. The url pattern should always be restricted by role.

Comment: Sorry, that tutorial does not help. I tried setting the session variables as suggested but get the same result.