# Spring-boot Spring Security; Users without the correct roles are still accessing role-specific pages

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I am attempting to make a web page that is only accessible by the 'Admin' role, however all users are able to access it. I have User and Role entities with a functioning ManyToMany relationship set up.

Here is my SecurityConfig.java:

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
private UserService userService;





@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
    .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers(
                "/registration",
                "/js/**",
                "/css/**",
                "/img/**",
                "/webjars/**").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
    .and()
        .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
    .and()
       .authorizeRequests()
           .antMatchers("/competition/**").hasRole("Admin")
    .and()
        .logout()
            .invalidateHttpSession(true)
            .clearAuthentication(true)
            .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout")
    .permitAll();
}




@Bean
public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}

@Bean
public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider(){
    DaoAuthenticationProvider auth = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
    auth.setUserDetailsService(userService);
    auth.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    return auth;
}

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
}
```

as you can see with the line

```
.antMatchers("/competition/**").hasRole("Admin")
```

I'm trying to make link /competition/** admin-only.

Here is the controller:

```
@Controller
public class CompetitionController {

@Autowired
CompetitionRepository competitionRepository;

@GetMapping("/competition/{competitors}")
public String match(ModelMap map, @PathVariable(value = "competitors") String competitors, Principal principal) {

    String[] parts = competitors.split("-");
    String part1 = parts[0]; 
    String part2 = parts[1];

    map.addAttribute("part1", part1);
    map.addAttribute("part2", part2);
    return "match";
}
```

}

Finally here is my UserService:

```
@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

@Autowired
private UserRepository userRepository;

@Autowired
private BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String email) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    User user = userRepository.findByEmail(email);
    if (user == null){
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Invalid username or password.");
    }
    return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.getEmail(),
            user.getPassword(),
            mapRolesToAuthorities(user.getRoles()));
}

public User findByEmail(String email){
    return userRepository.findByEmail(email);
}

public User save(UserRegistrationDto registration){
    User user = new User();
    user.setFirstName(registration.getFirstName());
    user.setLastName(registration.getLastName());
    user.setEmail(registration.getEmail());
    user.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(registration.getPassword()));
    user.setRoles(Arrays.asList(new Role("ROLE_USER")));

    User userAdmin = userRepository.findByEmail("admin@email.com");
    if (userAdmin == null){
       userAdmin = new User();
       userAdmin.setFirstName("Admin");
       userAdmin.setLastName("");
       userAdmin.setEmail("admin@email.com");
       userAdmin.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode("admin"));
       userAdmin.setRoles(Arrays.asList(new Role("ROLE_Admin")));

       userRepository.save(userAdmin);
    }


    return userRepository.save(user);
}

private Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> mapRolesToAuthorities(Collection<Role> roles){
    return roles.stream()
            .map(role -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getName()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
}
```

I attempted to change .hasRole to .hasAuthority as seen in this answer (to no avail): [Spring Security Java configuration for authenticated users with a role](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33673300/spring-security-java-configuration-for-authenticated-users-with-a-role).

Comment: This problem is already resolved. Please see the link.
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33673300/spring-security-java-configuration-for-authenticated-users-with-a-role)

Comment: Because that is what you configured... The ordering of the `authorizeRequests` and `antMatchers` is important. As the `authorizeRequests.permitAll` comes before the `authorizeRequests().antMatcher("/competition/**")` the first will match and your specific rule will be ignored. Basically you need to make sure that the `permitAll` is always the last.